# Using variables besides X and x in polynom package

Tags: layout, polynomials

Is there a way to make the polynom package accept variable labels other than x? If I try to typeset a polynomial long division using the variable T or t using that package, the output is screwed up, but it turns into something okay when I use x or X. I really wish this package were more flexible about accepting different labels for the variable.

Comment: The package manual says that the commands have an optional argument where you can specify a key-val-list and that one of the keys is `vars=...` for declaring what token you wish to use as variable. E.g., `\polylongdiv[vars=T]{T^3+T^2-1}{T-1}`. Does this not work?

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I did not see that before. You could post that as an answer if you want.